# How to center TextField inside Container?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to center the TextField inside Container but they are aligned to the left.

```
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Login'),
    ),
    body: Container(
        child: Column(          
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email Address'),
          ),width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        ),
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
          ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Pressed');
          },
          child: Text('Login'),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ],
    )));
```

}

How can I center the email and password TextField to the main Container?

Edit: I tried using the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` but it isnt working, although when I tried `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` it is centering the TextFields vertically.

Comment: If you have a prefixIcon, set isCollapsed to true.

Answer (score 4):

give `crossAxisAlignment` property to your column with `CrossAxisAlignment.center` value

```
Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
.
.
.
),
```

Comment: Using `mainAxisAlignment` will center all nested widgets vertically Instead you can suggest using `crossAxisAlignment`, which will also force the button to be centered.

Comment: then use align widget to align your button to left

Comment: I tried using `crossAxisAlignment` but that didnt center the TextFields horizontally, although trying `mainAxisAlignment` is aligning the TF vertically.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just add `textAlign: TextAlign.center` inside your `TextField`

```
 Container(
      child: TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email Address'),
      ),width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Hope it works for you.

```
Container(
      height: 36,
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: 1,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          prefixIcon:
              Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.fillColor,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          hintText: 'Search',
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Place each one of your `Textfield` inside a `Row` widget, and apply a `MainAxisAlignment.center` to each one of them:

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Login'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email Address'),
                    ),width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
                    ),width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Pressed');
                },
                child: Text('Login'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          )));
     }
```

I tried implementing other variants of this solution, but only by placing `Textfield` inside a `Row` I was able to center it.